# I can't install ubuntu 20.04 through USB stick

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I am trying to install ubuntu 20.04 through a USB stick (using UEFI).
My current setup is using Intel NUC8i7BEH. I am currently using Intel Iris Graphics 655 in the NUC. The Ubuntu iso file I am using is called ubuntu-20.04.6-desktop-amd64.

When I boot up the NUC, I would press f10 to enter the boot manager(I think that is what its called) and then boot the USB device. At the grub page, I choose the option "try or install ubuntu" and had to change quiet splash to "noacpi acpi=off" and then I boot. It would bring me to the home page when I would select try ubuntu. If I were to select install ubuntu I would be able to go through the entire process until the installation part where I would get the error:

```
Unable to Install GRUB in /dev/nvme
```

I searched the internet for answers where a page recommends me to use boot-repair.I then tried to install boot-repair using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt 
update
sudo apt install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

It would bring me to the boot repair application where I would run boot repair but would be faced with this error:

```
An error occured during the repair
Error:NVram is locked(ubuntu  not found in efibootmgr)
....
Locked-NVram detected
```

I have tried (and I apologise if I missed out something because I genuinely can't rmb anything rn)

1. Resetting my BIOS
2. Updating my BIOS to the latest version
3. Disabling UEFI password
4. Disabling secure boot and fast boot

So far I have not seen an actual solutions as many people seems to recommend different things but one of the more common things was talking about the EFI causing some issues. May I ask are there any solutions to solving either one of these problems?

Comment: Please edit your original question to add more details in order to help us help you: 1. Brand name and model of the computer; 2. Brand name and model of the graphics chip/card; 3. Full name of the Ubuntu iso file (for example `ubuntu-20.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso`); 4. Method and tool to put Ubuntu onto the USB stick; 5. Did you check with `sha256sum` that the iso file was downloaded currectly?

Comment: You mention both NVMe drive & sda. We may need details on install in addition to above info. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Why are you not trying with a newer version like 22.04?

Comment: See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2493148 as I prefer that if not a simple answer.

Comment: @sudodus I have added more details about my situation. I have not checked my iso file was downloaded correctly and will do so tmr however could this an issue with the iso file because it seems to be able to run ubuntu live?

Comment: @FedKad I tried to install version 22.04 and it gives me the same error too. However, the interface for boot-repair in 22.04 is different from the guides I see and from 20.04 so I decided to use 20.04

Comment: There's a thread on the "nvram locked" issue here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482909

Comment: @SunTofu, Thanks for adding info to your question. And I notice that you have an [active thread at the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2493148), which is a better location for a dialogue (and I think a dialogue will help in this case). I have an older NUC (6i3SYH), which is not affected by your problems, so I cannot help much in this case.